# SQL break while loop if exists

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I am trying to generate some fake addresses.
I have a table #Fakeaddess for example.

With few addresses:

```
Id | Apartment | House 
---------------------
1  |    2      |  13 
---------------------
2  |    3      |  13
---------------------
3  |    4      |  13 
---------------------
```

and etc.

What I want to do is generate additional apartments for this house

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 4
WHILE (@intFlag <=100)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #Fakeaddess 
    (Apartment, 
    House) 
    VALUES (
    @intFlag,
     13)
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Which works fine, howeber if I run the same query again by example it creates new apartments with new address id, which I don't want. Question is how to stop query running if the Apartment with same Number already exists.

I tried to use

```
 Where Apartment not in
  (
  SELECT Apartment 
  FROM #Fakeaddess
 )
```

in

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 4
WHILE (@intFlag <=100)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #Fakeaddess 
    (Apartment, 
    House) 
    VALUES (
    @intFlag,
     13) 
 Where Apartment not in
  (
  SELECT Apartment 
  FROM #Fakeaddess
 )

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

It does not work

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 4
WHILE (@intFlag <=100)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #Fakeaddess 
    (Apartment, 
    House) 
    VALUES (
    @intFlag,
     13) 
IF @intFlag in
  (
  SELECT Apartment 
  FROM #Fakeaddess
 )

BREAK

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Does not work either.

What I am missing here ?

Comment: Invalid SQL syntax used. You can't have `WHERE` clauses on an `INSERT INTO` statement for a start. Your second approach is getting closer to what you want. You want to check if a specific apartment exists so have you looked at [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator? You'll also have to filter your list of apartments by `@intFlag` which can be done in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why not just check if it does not exist, and if true then proceed with the insert otherwise nothing happens and you just continue on with your loop.